# forEach versus for in

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I have several things I am trying to replace with forEach (as is a requirement for a class I'm taking) however not one of them works:

My original For in code (This works correctly and displays the content):

```
for (var i in education.schools) {
        $('#education').append(HTMLschoolStart);

        var formattedName = HTMLschoolName.replace('%data%', education.schools[i].name).replace('#', education.schools[i].url);
        var formattedLocation = HTMLschoolLocation.replace('%data%', education.schools[i].location);
        var formattedDegree = HTMLschoolDegree.replace('%data%', education.schools[i].degree);
        var formattedMajors = HTMLschoolMajor.replace('%data%', education.schools[i].majors);
        var formattedDates = HTMLschoolDates.replace('%data%', education.schools[i].dates);
        var formattedNameDegree = formattedName + formattedDegree;


        $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedNameDegree);
        $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedDates);
        $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedLocation);
        $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedMajors);
    }
```

My forEach variation(Nothing is displayed, all content disappears):

```
education.schools.forEach(function() {
        $('#education').append(HTMLschoolStart);

        var formattedName = HTMLschoolName.replace('%data%', education.schools[i].name).replace('#', education.schools[i].url);
        var formattedLocation = HTMLschoolLocation.replace('%data%', education.schools[i].location);
        var formattedDegree = HTMLschoolDegree.replace('%data%', education.schools[i].degree);
        var formattedMajors = HTMLschoolMajor.replace('%data%', education.schools[i].majors);
        var formattedDates = HTMLschoolDates.replace('%data%', education.schools[i].dates);
        var formattedNameDegree = formattedName + formattedDegree;


        $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedNameDegree);
        $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedDates);
        $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedLocation);
        $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedMajors);
    })
```

The second one is an if statement that I am supposed to replace part of with a forEach.

The if statement works fine like this only problem is it is only good for exactly 7 items, if I were to add anymore to the array I would have to also update this:

```
if (bio.skills.length > 0) {
        $('#header').append(HTMLskillsStart);

        var formattedSkill = HTMLskills.replace('%data%', bio.skills[0]);
        $('#skills').append(formattedSkill);
        var formattedSkill = HTMLskills.replace('%data%', bio.skills[1]);
        $('#skills').append(formattedSkill);
        var formattedSkill = HTMLskills.replace('%data%', bio.skills[2]);
        $('#skills').append(formattedSkill);
        var formattedSkill = HTMLskills.replace('%data%', bio.skills[3]);
        $('#skills').append(formattedSkill);
        var formattedSkill = HTMLskills.replace('%data%', bio.skills[4]);
        $('#skills').append(formattedSkill);
        var formattedSkill = HTMLskills.replace('%data%', bio.skills[5]);
        $('#skills').append(formattedSkill);
        var formattedSkill = HTMLskills.replace('%data%', bio.skills[6]);
        $('#skills').append(formattedSkill);
    }
```

The forEach loop code(Instead of displaying each item in the array it displays ALL items in the array seven times, basically it does seem to iterate through it the correct number of times but outputs all 7 items to each iteration):

```
if (bio.skills.length > 0) {
        $('#header').append(HTMLskillsStart);

        bio.skills.forEach(function(){
            var formattedSkill = HTMLskills.replace('%data%', bio.skills);
            $('#skills').append(formattedSkill);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Because `i` doesn't exist in the forEach

Comment: [Don't use `for…in` enumerations on arrays!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring the index in the `forEach` callback function:

```
education.schools.forEach(function(val, i) {
    $('#education').append(HTMLschoolStart);

    var formattedName = HTMLschoolName.replace('%data%', education.schools[i].name).replace('#', education.schools[i].url);
    var formattedLocation = HTMLschoolLocation.replace('%data%', education.schools[i].location);
    var formattedDegree = HTMLschoolDegree.replace('%data%', education.schools[i].degree);
    var formattedMajors = HTMLschoolMajor.replace('%data%', education.schools[i].majors);
    var formattedDates = HTMLschoolDates.replace('%data%', education.schools[i].dates);
    var formattedNameDegree = formattedName + formattedDegree;


    $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedNameDegree);
    $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedDates);
    $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedLocation);
    $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedMajors);
});
```

Per [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> callback is invoked with three arguments:
>
> - the element value
> - the element index
> - the array being traversed

**EDIT**:

As [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas) mentions in the comments, if the `forEach` is running off of the `education.schools` array, then you can use the first parameter(`val`) in the callback instead of `education.schools[i]` to get the current item.

Comment: Why don't you use the current value directly instead of `education.schools[i]`?

Comment: @Andreas While that would work, the OP's question seems to stem from a lack of clarity on how to get the index in the `forEach` callback.

Comment: This should not be considered a complaint^^ But why don't we show the OP the next step which makes the `forEach` construct one step easier to handle :)

Comment: @Andreas I added an edit to the answer to include your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The for each callback gets three parameters passed:

- **currentValue** - the current element in the array
- **index** - the index of the ucrrent value
- **array** - the array itself

So you should use `currentValue.url` instead of `education.schools[i].name`.

```
education.schools.forEach(function(currentValue) {
    $('#education').append(HTMLschoolStart);

    var formattedName = HTMLschoolName.replace('%data%', currentValue.name).replace('#', currentValue.url);
    var formattedLocation = HTMLschoolLocation.replace('%data%', currentValue.location);
    var formattedDegree = HTMLschoolDegree.replace('%data%', currentValue.degree);
    var formattedMajors = HTMLschoolMajor.replace('%data%', currentValue.majors);
    var formattedDates = HTMLschoolDates.replace('%data%', currentValue.dates);
    var formattedNameDegree = formattedName + formattedDegree;


    $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedNameDegree);
    $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedDates);
    $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedLocation);
    $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedMajors);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your forEach is that you don't define `i`. To solve that you should replace the `i` for a existing variable, or define `i`.

Your code could be like this:

```
education.schools.forEach(function() {
    $('#education').append(HTMLschoolStart);

    var formattedName = HTMLschoolName.replace('%data%', this.name).replace('#', this.url);
    var formattedLocation = HTMLschoolLocation.replace('%data%', this.location);
    var formattedDegree = HTMLschoolDegree.replace('%data%', this.degree);
    var formattedMajors = HTMLschoolMajor.replace('%data%', this.majors);
    var formattedDates = HTMLschoolDates.replace('%data%', this.dates);
    var formattedNameDegree = formattedName + formattedDegree;


    $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedNameDegree);
    $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedDates);
    $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedLocation);
    $('.education-entry:last').append(formattedMajors);
})
```

Note that the main change is the use of `this` instead of `education.schools[i]`.